# Tensor Product of the fraction field of the Gaussian Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]=\left\{a+bi:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$  be the ring of Gaussian integers $(i^{2}=-1)$ and let $\mathbb{Q}[i]=\left\{a+bi:a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ be its fraction field.

> 1) Show that the tensor product $\mathbb{Q}[i] \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}[i]$ is isomorphic to the product $\mathbb{Q}[i] \times \mathbb{Q}[i]$ of two copies of the field.
>
> 2) Let $S=\left\{1,2,2^2,2^3,...\right\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ be the multiplicatively closed subset generated by 2. Find two distinct idempotents in the algebra $S^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}[i] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[i])$ other than $0$ and $1$.

For the first part, I thought I would try to use the presentation $\mathbb{Q}[i] \simeq \mathbb{Q}[T]/(T^2+1)$ and see what comes from that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: By $\mathbb Z(i)$, you mean $\mathbb Z\left[i\right]$ ?

Comment: I agree with Darij, I doubt you meant parentheses. As for 1) you can use the fact that if $R$ is an $A$-algebra then $R\otimes_A A[t]/(f(t))\cong R[t]/(f(t))$.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right! I'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) In [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520644/idempotents-in-mathbbzi-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbzi) you can find that $\mathbb Z[i]\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z[i]\cong\mathbb Z[i][X]/(X^2+1)$ and this implies that $S^{-1}(\mathbb Z[i]\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z[i])\cong(S^{-1}\mathbb Z)[i][X]/(X^2+1)=\mathbb Z[\frac 12,i][X]/(X^2+1)$. Following the same calculations you get that $\frac 12\pm(\frac 12i)x$ are the nontrivial idempotents.