# Idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}[i] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Letting $\mathbb{Z}[i]=\left\{a+bi:a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ be the ring of Gaussian integers, how many idempotents are there in $\mathbb{Z}[i] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[i]$?

I came across this in my reading, and I'm a little unsure of how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Geometrically, the spectrum of $\mathbb Z[i]\otimes_\mathbb Z\mathbb Z[i]$ is two copies of the spectrum of $\mathbb Z[i]$ meeting each other above the point $2\mathbb Z$ of $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb Z$. So it is connected, which means there is no idempotent different from $0$ and $1$.

Comment: It might be nice to note what goes wrong with the "obvious proof" that the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}[i]\otimes\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has four idempotents. Namely, this ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]/(x^2+1)$. Now $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$, and so we can CRT this to get the product of two integral domains, so four idempotents, right? Wrong. The issue is that while $x-i$ and $x+i$ are coprime, since $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$ is not a PID (it has dimension 2) this does not imply that $(x-i)$ and $(x+i)$ are comaximal! In fact, they jointly generate $(2)$ which is consistent with Cantlog's geometric picture.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160853/connectedness-of-the-spectrum-of-a-tensor-product) for the general case of tensor product of rings of integers.

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\mathbb{Z}[i] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[i]\cong\Bbb Z[i][X]/(X^2+1).$$ Every element of the ring $\Bbb Z[i][X]/(X^2+1)$ can be uniquely written as $a+bx$, with $x^2=-1$. If $(a+bx)^2=a+bx$, then $a^2-b^2=a$ and $2ab=b$. Now we have two cases: $b=0$ and $a=0,1$ or $b\ne 0$ and then $a=1/2\notin\Bbb Z$. It follows that $0,1$ are the only idempotents.